# Java: method of a method

Tags: java, list, methods

I have the following Code below which is a doubly linked list. Ignore the comments for now. (I've copied the vital parts from somewhere on github, so don't be surprised if you find something similar).

My question is very basic and I need the following Expression:

n.next of n.previous.

If I'm not mistaken, n.next and n.previous are both methods.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance

```
public class DoublyLinkedList {

int size =0;
Knoten head = null;
Knoten tail = null;


public Knoten addAtEnd(int data){
    Knoten n = new Knoten(data);
    if(size==0){
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    }else{
        tail.next = n;
        n.previous = tail;
        tail =n;
    }
    size++;
    return n;
}

public Knoten Search(int data)
{
    Knoten n = new Knoten(data);
    /*for i in DoublyLinkedList
    /*if hat n.data = data(of parameter)
     * {n.next of previous n n is now : n.next
     * n.previous of next n = n previous
     * }
     */
    size--;
    return n;
}

public Knoten delete(int data)
{
    Knoten n = new Knoten(data);
    if(n.previous != null)
    {

    /*  n.next of n.previous = n.next
     * n.previous of n.previous = n previous
     */
    }
    else {
        // n.next is now head
    }

    size--;
    return n;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoublyLinkedList d = new DoublyLinkedList();
    d.addAtEnd(3);
}
```

}

```
class Knoten
{
    int data;
    Knoten next;
    Knoten previous;

    public Knoten(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
        previous = null;  
    }
}
```

Comment: they aren't methods...

Comment: So you want `n.previous.next`?

Comment: Say, I have a list of 1 , 4 , 6

n = 4

n.previous.next would be 4 right?
so n.previous.next = n.next would be 6 right?

Comment: No @A.Y n.previous().next() == n -- n==4, go back one (previous) to 1, then forward one (next) to 4 again.

Comment: if you set `n.previous.next = n.next`, you change the `next` reference of `n.previous`. Since `n` references `4`, `n.previous` references `1` and `n.next` references `6`. Thus, the statement sets the `next` reference of `1` to `6`.

Comment: But if I assign n.previous.next = n.next and n.next.previous = n.previous with n=4 i would practically get that 1's next would be 6 and 6's previous would be 1, right?

Comment: @A.Y why don't you try it out?

Answer (score 0):

That class `Knoten` implements a [doubly linked list pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list), so that `next`, `previous` are pointers to the beginning and ending nodes in the list, needed to traverse the list. The linked list can be depicted here:

[image]

[This](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/DoublyLinkedList.java.html) class `DoublyLinkedList` is a simple implementation in Java.
You can see here how `next()` and `previous()` can be implemented as methods:

```
        public Item next() {
            if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            lastAccessed = current;
            Item item = current.item;
            current = current.next; 
            index++;
            return item;
        }

        public Item previous() {
            if (!hasPrevious()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            current = current.prev;
            index--;
            lastAccessed = current;
            return current.item;
        }
```

but this is not how they acted in the `Knoten` class.